# Intercept Arrow key and send Enter instead

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Using pure JS I'd like to intercept the arrow key and dispatch the enter key in its place to submit a form. The enter key is being dispatched it's just not behaving like the enter key does when you physically push it on the keyboard, I know I could just use `click()` to do the same thing its just really bothering me that I cant get the enter key to work how I expect..

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devnsyde/w5x1m2pk/)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('name');
input.addEventListener('keydown', e => handleArrowNavigation(e));

function handleArrowNavigation(event) {
  if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
    //send enter to expand
    triggerEnterKey(event.target.id);
  }
}

function triggerEnterKey(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element) {
    const keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: "Enter",
      //code: "Enter",
      //keyCode: 13,
      //charCode: 13,
      //type: "keydown",
      //isTrusted: true,
      //defaultPrevented: true,
      //currentTarget: element,
      //view: window,
      //bubbles: true
    });

    var dispatched = element.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
    console.log("enter key triggered on element: " + element.id);
    console.log("event dispatched: ", dispatched);

    //element.click();//click works
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript: alert('form submitted.')">
  <p>
    If you hit enter while focus is on the input you will get an alert as expected. If you click the right arrow key I'd like it to trigger the enter key and do what enter does. (right arrow key should trigger form submission alert)
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually just figured this out... You can't.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Note: Manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.